# WikiJS install stuck on Rebuilding Page Tree

Tags: javascript, powershell, iis, wiki

Using WikiJS v2.5.296
Windows Server 2019

I ran the setup for WikiJS and Powershell produced this log. It has been stuck here for about 1 hour now.

Any advice is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the `-d` flag in your command. Just refer to this wiki.js official support case: https://github.com/requarks/wiki/discussions/5695.